# How to POST data from form in mongodb using ajax?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I want to post form data to my mongodb database using AJAX jQuery, but it is not reflecting data there. Its showing as `Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

index.js(nodeJs)

```
app.post('/students/student', function(req,res){
    db.collection('students').insertOne(req.data,function(error,result){
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(result)
        res.redirect('/student');
    })
})
```

add.js

```
$('#submit').click(function () { 
    var data={
        name:$('#name').val(),
        email:$('#email').val(),
        phone:$('#phone').val(),
        age:$('#age').val()
    }
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/students/student",
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data:JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
    }
}); });
```

add.html

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="formData">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student's Name" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Id." id="email" required>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
     <div class="col-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No." id="phone" required>
    </div>
     <div class="col-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" id="age" required>
    </div> 
  </div> <br><br>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button  class="btn btn-outline-warning " id="submit" >Submit</button></div>

</form>
</div>
```

At the console side it is saying this `POST http://localhost:3000/students/student 500 (Internal Server Error)`
This should make a POST request to an API endpoint students/student.
And should use an AJAX script in an external JS file for this.
The API endpoint should make relevant entries in the MongoDB collection

Comment: Does it work from Postman?

Comment: can you show server logs? As its throwing 500 that means your code is breaking at some line at backend.

Comment: @SandeepPatel figured it out, in index.js instead of ``` req.data``` i corrected it as ``` req.body``` and now this works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting button type.

```
`<button type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-warning " id="submit" >Submit</button></div>`
```

Comment: please read his question carefully and change your answer accordingly